# load class "PhoneNumberUtil" from namespace "libphonenumber"

Tags: symfony, libphonenumber

I have this error while I have just updated my server, I have the following error:

```
Attempted to load class "PhoneNumberUtil" from namespace "libphonenumber".
Did you forget a "use" statement for "libphonenumber\PhoneNumberUtil"?

500 Internal Server Error - ClassNotFoundException
```

So I got error 500 every time: / someone could help me solve my problem please?

Comment: where is located the class PhoneNumberUtil? Which namespace? Is a vendor class? How do you install/autoload (Composer reference...)?

Comment: PhoneNumberUtil is located in vendor\giggsey\libphonenumber-for-php\src\libphonenumber

Comment: In local everything works, but as soon as I put the update online on the FTP, it made me this 500 error

Comment: possibly a cache/autoloader problem?

Comment: can you log via shell to the system and do a `composer install` in order to recreate the autoloader?